# Getting list of pids and process names

Tags: command-line, macos

By running `ps aux` I can get list running processes with *command* associated with them, e.g.

```
USER               PID  %CPU %MEM      VSZ    RSS   TT  STAT STARTED      TIME COMMAND
_windowserver      142   2.0  1.3  4559968 224672   ??  Ss    7:11AM  33:21.95 /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SkyLight.framework/Resources/WindowServer -daemon
lrogalsk          6419   1.9  0.5  2703580  77588   ??  S     2:15PM   0:40.88 /Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app/Contents/MacOS/Terminal
...
```

Unfortunately, `COMMAND` includes command line arguments and absolute path of file, both of which may contain spaces. How can I get *process name* in deterministic manner?

Comment: Did you look at `man ps`?

Answer (score 5):

Apparently I'm blind.

```
 -c      Change the ``command'' column output to just contain the executable name, rather than the full
         command line.
```

`ps auxc` works just fine.

```
USER               PID  %CPU %MEM      VSZ    RSS   TT  STAT STARTED      TIME COMMAND
lrogalsk         18670  15.6  1.4  3913100 241624   ??  Ss   12:12PM   0:09.93 com.apple.WebKit.WebContent
```

Answer (score 0):

A resounding  `ps -eco comm`

To wrap that good in double-quotes, here is this regex monster:

```
ps -eco comm | sed "s/.*:......//" | sed "s/^/\"/" | sed "s/$/\"/" | grep -v COMMAND
```

Took me about a day or two to write, and had bugs when using `ps axc` until @wildcard showed me the light of -eco comm. I'm planning to create a task killer with it one day I will call it MadsKills. Anyhow remove the last two pipes to sed to get rid of the quotes.

On my system this gives:

```
"(mysqld)"
"-zsh"
"iTerm2"
"login"
"-zsh"
"ssh"
"-zsh"
"ps"
"sed"
"sed"
```

Works great on macOS and linux also.

Comment: That’s painfully hacky.  If all you want is the process name, use the appropriate flags per “man ps” to output only the process name.

Comment: @wildcard this is macos - what flags are these to only show process name? So I can send to killall

Comment: Look at the man page.  `ps -co comm` or `ps -eco comm` are some starting points.  But also, you don't need to write a task killer.  Just kill the task you want to kill.  Also see `pkill` and `pgrep`.

Comment: Or use `ps axc | sed -n 's|^.*:..\... \(.*\)|"\1"|p'` for hacky, without requiring `grep -v` :-)

Comment: thanks @wildcard I have incorporated your idea and also added grep to remove COMMAND from the list.

Comment: @nohillside Wow it's a co-incidence you posted just 3 mins before i updated my answer to be much much better.

Comment: I was just looking at your answer and trying to come up with even more hacky ways. But the `ps -eco comm` way is better overall anyway